# From a hosts point of view, which comes first, effect of toxins on pathways or identification of toxins by immune system?

Tags: molecular-biology, bacteriology, infectious-diseases, pathogenesis, host-pathogen-interaction

From a pure biology perspective, when a pathogen (gram-negative bacteria) affects a host by secreting toxins, what comes first, the effect of the toxin on the pathways or identification of the toxin by the immune system? A generalized overview would be very helpful.

Comment: That really depends on the toxin: Some of them are toxic in so low doses that they are never recognised by the immune system (like Tetanus toxin). So it would be good if you could clarify the question towards a specific toxin.

Comment: @Chris I have edited the question. Does that help?